# how to properly templatize certain bash routines in gitlab cicd ??

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab deployment CD yaml file which takes in inputs and sets up an environment.. but I need to sometimes cleanup the inputs in bash before I use certain variables (For instance I want to use the branch name in the environment being created in juju.. but juju models cannot contain `/` characters.

What is the proper way to templatize routines so I don't have to line-for-line repeat them?  seems there are directives in gitlab CICD but those are static routines.. and I was hoping to have something dynamic

example .gitlab-ci.yaml

```
deploy-staging-lxd-upstream:
  tags:
    - Juju, staging
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: staging-lxd
  script:
    - echo $UPSTREAM_PROJECT - $UPSTREAM_BRANCH - $UPSTREAM_PROJECT_ID - $UPSTREAM_PACKAGE_VERSION - $UPSTREAM_OP_FILENAME
    - ls -la
    - SAFE_BRANCH_NAME=$(echo "$UPSTREAM_BRANCH"|tr '/' '-')
    - SAFE_BRANCH_NAME=$(echo "$SAFE_BRANCH_NAME"|tr '_' '-')
    - juju switch "mahrio-upstream-$UPSTREAM_PROJECT_ID-$SAFE_BRANCH_NAME" || true
```

how can i extract this

```
    - SAFE_BRANCH_NAME=$(echo "$UPSTREAM_BRANCH"|tr '/' '-')
    - SAFE_BRANCH_NAME=$(echo "$SAFE_BRANCH_NAME"|tr '_' '-')
```

and just .. create a bash routine that I put in any branch name.. and a "safe" branch name comes back out for use in subsequent `-script` calls?  or is it better to just do this in python or some other language than bash.. and put that logic in a pypi module across my CICD ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `tr 'abc' '-'`?

```
- SAFE_BRANCH_NAME=$(echo "$UPSTREAM_BRANCH"|tr '/_' '-')
```

See `man tr` for details on how it treats more characters in `string1` than `string2`:

```
$ man tr
SYNOPSIS
     tr [-Ccsu] string1 string2
     tr [-Ccu] -d string1
     tr [-Ccu] -s string1
     tr [-Ccu] -ds string1 string2

     [...]

     In the first synopsis form, the characters in string1 are translated into
     the characters in string2 where the first character in string1 is
     translated into the first character in string2 and so on.  If string1 is
     longer than string2, the last character found in string2 is duplicated
     until string1 is exhausted.
```

Comment: I dont think you followed the question.. the question is how to templatize and make this bash routine reusable across multiple projects .. so that I do not copy paste this across multiple jobs.. I am thinking I need to write the bash into a function , include it, and call the function in the job.. but unsure

Comment: i tried https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#use-default-configuration-from-an-included-configuration-file and it doesn't even run (or the output isn't showing)